# "invalid %N$ use detected" vlfeat sift error

Tags: matlab, sift, vlfeat

I have used the **vlfeat** toolbox and the **vl_sift**, lot of times with no problem. I decided to use it in **Matlab R2009a**, with **ubuntu 14.04**. This is the error I get while running vl_setup()

```
    ??? XML-file failed validation against schema located in:
    /home/tonystark/Matlab_prg/sys/namespace/info/v1/info.xsd

    XML-file name:
    /home/tonystark/freelancing/Content_based_image_retrieval/code/new_code/vlfeat-0.9.18/toolbox/info.xml
    To retest the XML-file against the schema, call the following java method:
    com.mathworks.xml.XMLValidator.validate(...
'/home/tonystark/freelancing/Content_based_image_retrieval/code/new_code/vlfeat-0.9.18/toolbox/info.xml',...
    '/home/tonystark/Matlab_prg/sys/namespace/info/v1/info.xsd', true)

    Errors:
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
    starting with element 'help_contents_icon'. One of '{product_name_ends_with_type,
    help_addon, preference_panel, dialogpref_registrar, project_plugin, state_item, list}'
    is expected.
```

But when I run the same code **again**, the error doesn't come and the code **vl_setup** compiles, but **no output displayed**

And when I run this sample code

```
    clc;
    close all;
    clear all;

    I1 = imread('/home/tonystark/freelancing/Content_based_image_retrieval/Dataset/all_souls_000140.jpg');
    I2 = imread('/home/tonystark/freelancing/Content_based_image_retrieval/Dataset/all_souls_000146.jpg');

    [f1 d1] = vl_sift(single(rgb2gray(I1)));
    [f2 d2] = vl_sift(single(rgb2gray(I2)));
```

matlab crashes with the following error on the terminal

```
    *** invalid %N$ use detected ***
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am stuck here for quite some time without any specific direction. If somebody can point me in the right direction or solve this, it would be of great help! Your help is much appreciated.

**UPDATE 1**

The readme file of vlfeat says it requires matlab 2009b min, for the toolbox to work. could that be a reason?

Comment: It is an issue with the version. nothing else.

Comment: the previous version has different schema, compared to the one present from 2009b. So that is conflicting